# how do i parse a <td> tag content from html that consist of more than one table that have no class or id?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the example :

```
<table width="98%" border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" style="border: 1px solid #9fc1d6;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#F8F8F8">Rooms </td>
            <td bgcolor="#F8F8F8">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FDFDFD">Rest room </td>
            <td bgcolor="#FDFDFD">3</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>


<table width="98%" border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" style="border: 1px solid #9fc1d6">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="ch5">contact person </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="26%" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">Name</td>
        <td width="74%" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">Silvilia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FDFDFD">Phone Number</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FDFDFD">0852-2223-44xx</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

In this case, I want to parse `td` tag content of rooms (4). So here's the example code to get td tag content of rooms, if it only one table.

```
var row = $('table tr');
row.each(function(j,elem){
    if(j==1){
        var rooms= $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        dataparse.rooms = rooms;
    }
});
```

is there any way to help this problem ?

Comment: You have two `<td>`s and manage to get right one, then you ask how to deal with two `<table>`s.

Comment: yes correct and the main question is how do i separate between those two <table>s?

Comment: How do you separate between two `<td>`s?

Answer (score 0):

if you can't add class or id, there is no convenient ways.
Your approach is good and should work, but you are fetching data from second row (Rest room), because index `j` should start from 0, and you are doing comparation `j == 1`. In other way to do it, you can try to use xpath, or you can check innerHTML of previous cell (if `innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()` of prev cell is equal to `rooms`.